# How to turn an array into an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like

```
let arr = [
  { key: "Text1", value: "Line 1" },
  { key: "Text2", value: "Line 2" },
  { key: "Text3", value: "Line 3" }
]
```

and I want to turn it into

```
let obj = {
  "Text1": "Line1",
  "Text2": "Line2",
  "Text3": "Line3"
}
```

in es6 i was trying something like this but that's definitely wrong.  Any help please?

```
let temp = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map( {key, value} => ( {key, value} ) ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and a destructuring and a spread syntex for the items of the mapped objects.

Basically you need more parenthesis around the arguments and a computed key.

```
Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })));
//                           ^              ^                          parenthesis
//                                                  ^   ^              computed property
```

```js
let arr = [{ key: "Text1", value: "Line 1" }, { key: "Text2", value: "Line 2" }, { key: "Text3", value: "Line 3" }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value })));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When I try to use the syntax `result = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map` I get a syntax error at `...arr.map`

Comment: @Jodo1992, which browser are you using? does your browser suppports ES6?

Comment: Not using a browser. This is involved with a mobile app. Just trying to accomplish the same exact thing the OP was trying to do in JS

Comment: maybe it is not ES6 compliant, but i am wondering why `Object.assign` is working.

Comment: The problem I don't think is `Object.assign`, it is the syntax `...arr.map`. It doesn't not know what to do with the punctuation

Comment: you could use `apply` with an array for the parameters, exactly what `...` is in short form doing.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this with reduce:

```
arr.reduce((o, el) => { 
    o[el.key] = el.value; 
    return o; 
}, {});
```

returns

```
{Text1: "Line 1", Text2: "Line 2", Text3: "Line 3"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
let arr = [
      { key: "Text1", value: "Line 1" },
      { key: "Text2", value: "Line 2" },
      { key: "Text3", value: "Line 3" }
    ]

    var obj ={};
    arr.forEach(function(value){
    obj[value.key]=value.value;
    })

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
let arr = [{ key: "Text1", value: "Line 1" }, { key: "Text2", value: "Line 2" }, { key: "Text3", value: "Line 3" }],
    result = arr.reduce((r,k)=>(r[k.key]=k.value,r),{});
    console.log(result);
```